# oauth token for sinatra oauth2-provider

Tags: sinatra, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I am new to Sinatra and want to get it working with oauth2-provider gem. I followed instruction https://github.com/songkick/oauth2-provider#readme and looked at example. But after i've got access_token, i can't get information from Oauth endpoint using this. It generate 401 not Unauthorized error. From my application i do request 
http://localhost:9292/me?access_token=, i've tried html request as well as json request, but without success.

Anybody faced with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did your request using HTTP vs HTTPS. Did you try setting `Songkick::OAuth2::Provider.enforce_ssl = false` for now?